# associated data & displayField cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have shipments, orders and users.  When I try and set up a new shipment, the Order displayField is showing up correctly as the label in my select dropdown.  The User though is only showing the actual id of the user instead of the displayField.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm using admin scaffolding.  Is that the problem?

```
class Shipment extends ShipmentsAppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('Order', 'User');
}

class Order extends AppModel {
  public $belongsTo = array('User');
  public $name = 'Order';
  public $displayField = 'title';
}
class User extends UsersAppModel {
public $displayField = 'email';
}
```

Comment: can you please add your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing, `UsersAppModel` extends by `User`. It should `AppModel` according to CakePHP convention. `Order` is Extending `AppModel` and its working as u expect.

Try to use `AppModel` instead of `UsersAppModel`. The `$displayField` inherits from `AppModel` automatically, its a magic variable, defined in CakePHP core with default `id` field. Re-using that variable that variable in our model we just re-write that value and here `AppModel` is the linker.

But, here I think `UsersAppModel` has no relation with CakePHP core model inheritance like `AppModel` and that is the point of issue.

So instead of

```
class User extends UsersAppModel {
   public $displayField = 'email';
}
```

use

```
class User extends AppModel {
   public $displayField = 'email';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your code syntax

it should be

```
class Shipment extends AppModel {}
```

and

```
class User extends AppModel{}
```